# make array multidimensional values and key pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How i get below output in javascript

```
var keys = ["1","2","3"];
var values = ["one", "two","three"];


var final = {
    "1": "one",
    "2": "two",
    "3": "three"
}
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Can you show your code so far?

Comment: Question shows a lack of research or code attempt to resolve issue. You are expected to have at least tried something and if you did post the code that wasn't working

Answer (score 3):

Loop over one of the arrays and use the index to access the other, save in an object

```
var result = {};

keys.forEach(function(item, index) {
   result[item] = values[index]; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple loop should suffice, copying the values & keys at each index into a new object:

```
var finalOutput = {};
for(var i=0, j=keys.length; i<j; i++) {
    finalOutput[keys[i]] = values[i];
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jno5ue0a/)

**Note**: You shouldn't use `final` as a variable name as it is a [reserved future keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)